# How to delete 10000 items from a Custom list in sharepoint using powershell script

Tags: sharepoint

my sharepoint site list is having too many items and i need to delete 10000 files from it.How to do that using powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

Create the query:

```
$list =  (Get-Spweb http://devmy101).GetList("http://devmy101/Lists/smarEnteredTerritorialWaters")
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery;
$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";
$query.RowLimit = 2000;
$query.Query = '<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name="Created"/><Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="TRUE">2013-07-10T14:20:00Z</Value></Gt></Where>';
```

Build the command (note the query is limited to returning 2000 items at a time, and uses the ListItemCollectionPosition property to continue retrieving items in batches of 2000 until all the items have been queried. See this MSDN documentation for more info.)

```
$itemCount = 0;
$listId = $list.ID;
[System.Text.StringBuilder]$batchXml = New-Object "System.Text.StringBuilder";
$batchXml.Append("<?xml version=`"1.0`" encoding=`"UTF-8`"?><Batch>");
$command = [System.String]::Format( "<Method><SetList>{0}</SetList><SetVar Name=`"ID`">{1}</SetVar><SetVar Name=`"Cmd`">Delete</SetVar></Method>", $listId, "{0}" );

do
{
    $listItems = $list.GetItems($query)
    $query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
    foreach ($item in $listItems)
    {
        if($item -ne $null){$batchXml.Append([System.String]::Format($command, $item.ID.ToString())) | Out-Null;$itemCount++;}
    }
}
while ($query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)

$batchXml.Append("</Batch>");
$itemCount;
```

And lastly (and most importantly!), run the query

```
$web = Get-Spweb http://inceweb/HKMarineDB;
$web.ProcessBatchData($batchXml.ToString()) | Out-Null;
```

You will want to run this in SharePoint Management Shell as Admin.
This is verbatim takin from a blog post by Matthew Yarlett. I posted the majority of the post here incase his blog ever goes away. http://matthewyarlett.blogspot.com/2013/07/well-that-was-fun-bulk-deleting-items.html